# To show that $T^{-1}=T^{*}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

This is given as exercise problem in Functional analysis by Conway.It says if T$\in B(H,K)$,(where H and K are Hilbert spaces and T is continuous linear operator), then T is an isomorphism if and only if T is invertible and $T^{-1}=T^{*}$. Initially I thought it will be very easy and I have proved everything but I just couldn't find the reason why $T^{-1}=T^{*}$. Basically, I have to prove that $<Tx,y>=<x,T^{-1}y> \forall x\in H,y\in K $. But I am stuck. Any hint. Thanks.

Comment: This is false already for $H=K=\mathbb R$. Take $T=2$. Then $T^*=2$ but $T^{-1}=1/2$.

Comment: If this is an exercise from Conway, perhaps some context has been omitted?

Comment: It probably says "isometric isomorphism".

Comment: @daw I think Conway means "isomorphism in the category of Hilbert spaces" (or maybe in the category of normed spaces), which means it must be an isometric linear isomorphism.

Comment: sorry for confusion..i will edit the question

Comment: Check the definition of "isomorphism" that Conway gives. Unless it is quite unexpected, that will make the exercise either very easy, or clearly wrong.

Comment: Note that an arbitrary $y\in K$ is the same as $Tz$ for arbitrary $z\in H$, since $T$ is onto. Then $\forall x,z\in H,\ \langle Tx,Tz\rangle=\langle x,z\rangle=\langle x,T^{-1}Tz\rangle$. The first equation is due to $T$ preserving the norm and the [polarization identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity).

Comment: oh..you guys are right..he actually means "isometric isomorphism" by just "isomorphism"...thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If $T\in B(H,K)$ is an isometric isomorphism, then $\langle x,x\rangle=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle =\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle$, or $\langle (I_H-T^*T)x,x\rangle=0$ for all $x\in H$.  Since $I_H-T^*T$ is self-adjoint, Corollary 2.14 of chapter II in Conway's book implies that $T^*T=I_H$, and similarly we see that $TT^*=I_K$.

Comment: Isn't $(Ax|x)=(Bx|x) \forall x \implies A=B$ only true in complex Hilbert spaces?

Comment: This is true for arbitrary Hilbert spaces, assuming that $A-B$ is self-adjoint. I edited my answer to include a reference to a proof of this fact from Conway's book.